# delete from database not working using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $Team = $_POST['Team'];
    echo "$Team" ; 
    $sql = "DELETE FROM championsleauge WHERE Team = $Team "; 
    if($con->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
        echo "New delete successfully";
    } 

}
```

the delete is not working. it does echo the team name to be deleted any ideas?

Comment: echo $sql and run query direct in mysql database and check error.

Comment: `$Team` must be a string. Mind adding some error checking to your code? And some ***protection***?

Comment: Query have an error. Use `$Team` in single quote. It's string.

Comment: besides the fact you should use PDO etc etc. Use quotes around your variables to let it work.  Readup:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: What do you think happens when I fill in this string in team: `'test' OR 1=1`

Comment: Use `try{} catch{}` instead `if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ***does not*** answer your question, but it can open your eyes!

```
DELETE FROM championsleauge WHERE Team = $Team
```

Send this value to your POST variable named Team

```
5 OR 1=1
```

It will become

```
DELETE FROM championsleauge WHERE Team = 5 OR 1=1
```

And there you go, **no more champion leagues**!

BTW, your error is a simple typo. String values need to be quoted. Then you have no error checking at all. Then you need to go through

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

PDO is not as scary as it sounds, you code can be as simple as this

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', $user, $password);
$sth=$dbh-prepare("DELETE FROM championsleauge WHERE Team = ?");
$sth->execute(array($Team));
```

Comment: hey i know i can use i think html entities to prevent sql injection ?  just under a bit of pressure to get a working prototype for a demo

Comment: See the updated answer